# TSQL Group By Calculation Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

My issue is a bit difficult to explain. I have a table full of products, and I need to select the first letter of each product, like so:

```
SELECT      LEFT(PRODUCTS.ProductName, 1)
```

But then, I need to calculate all products that begin with a letter, and have that in a second column. For example: Product bread and product butter. I then need to have the letter 'B' in the first column, and '2' in the second, because there are two products that begin with the letter 'B'.

```
SELECT      LEFT(PRODUCTS.ProductName, 1),
            COUNT(PRODUCTS.ProductName)
FROM        PRODUCTS
GROUP BY    PRODUCTS.ProductName
```

The above code, however, gives me all products with all letters, and the result is '1' each time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: GROUP BY LEFT(PRODUCTS.ProductName, 1),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by all of the fields which distinguish your data for the aggregation.

In this case, you can't group by `ProductName` because that's not what you're actually counting - you're trying to count up how many `ProductName`s *start with* each letter.

Your `Group By` needs to match your `SELECT` - `LEFT(PRODUCTS.ProductName,1)`

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table, like this...

```
SELECT
    [First Letter],
    COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        LEFT(Products.ProductName, 1) AS [First Letter]
    FROM
        Products
    ) DerivedFirstLettersOnly
GROUP BY
    [First Letter]
ORDER BY
    [First Letter] ASC
```

The derived table is not required here, but it more explicitly lays out that you need to first get the first letter, then do the count.  As others have pointed out, this can be done all at once without the derived table.